# Where can I find "categories" which I can use for L2 practice by listing words in those categories?

Tags: resource-request

[A Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/languagelearning/comments/xeuvcw/language_challenge_name_5/) has an exercise of listing 5 different things in each category:

> A1: colors
> A2: rooms of a house
> B1: sea creatures
> B2: chemical elements
> C1: ways to cook an egg
> C2/impossible: construction equipment

I'm finding this a fun exercise, and useful for thinking up vocabulary I might not otherwise use.

**Question**: Where can I find "categories" which I can use for L2 practice by listing words in those categories?

It seems like this is a game called [categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categories_(word_game)):

> [image: the game "categories"]

I'd like to be able to do this with my iTalki teacher.

Comment: Why don't you make up your own?

Answer (score 0):

There's a mobile game called "Scatter Categories", which can generate lists like:

> [image: Categories: celebrities, reasons to make a phone call, holidays, ...]

You can ignore the game and just use the categories for vocabulary practice.